# How to interpret the phase of the complex covariance between two analytic signals?

Tags: covariance, bivariate

I am looking at the covariance between two complex signals. I understand envelope (aka modulus, magnitude) covariance well enough. The covariance between signal envelopes is always smaller than the variance (or auto-covariance).

However, I am unsure of the interpretation of the phase (aka atan2, angle)  of the covariance. Intuitively one might expect that phase of covariance would be equivalent to the covariance of phase, but this is not so. As angles are already scaled, the variance  of a sample of angles [-pi pi] is pi, but the phase of complex variance is always zero (variance is always real).

How does one interpret the phase of a complex covariance?

Comment: One reason not to expect the phase of the covariance to be the covariance of the phases--besides the fact that phases are only defined modulo $2\pi$--is that the phase is the (imaginary part of the) logarithm.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you might check out the geometric interpretation of complex covariance I describe in my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215982/covariance-matrix-of-complex-random-variables). For covariance between variables $z$ and $w$, essentially the real part is the covariance between $z$ and the "parallel" (in phase) component of $w$, while the imaginary is the covariance between $z$ and the "perpendicular" (90 degrees out of phase) component of $w$.

Comment: Those explanations are very helpful, thank you @GeoMatt22.

Comment: I am interested in this question as well. I read the interesting @GeoMatt22's answer, but it is about real and imaginary part. Any insights about the phase of a complex covariance?